# DBMS one to one relationship

Tags: database, entity-relationship, relation

This question is self made.

Suppose , i have an ER diagram and want to know how many minimum tables are required to represent that ER diagram.

Now, I have 3 entities, A,B and C.

A and B have one to one relationship. Similarly, B and C have one to one relationship. I have learn't that one to one relationship does not requires a seperate table.

Am i thinking correct, to merge all three tables to a single one ?

AB has one to one , BC has one to one , so AC will also be having one to one ?

Plz help me as i am newbie to this topic...

Comment: This may help http://www.learndb.com/databases/how-to-convert-er-diagram-to-relational-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In above diagram,
A ->  B and B -> C has one to one relationship and
A -> C is also one to one.

Comment: thanks, this is a nice explaination. So, ABC can be merged to make a single table ?

Comment: Yes it can be merged into a single table.